# TSQL Syntax error when surrounding CASE Statement with Parenthesis

Tags: t-sql, case

I have code where I am inserting records into a temp table. It generates the following errors:
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 185
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 186
Incorrect syntax near 'TI'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 187
Incorrect syntax near 'S1'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 189
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 191
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 193
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 195
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

(The following code starts on line 178 of my code:)
 Insert into #Month18Result

```
SELECT TI.EQId, 'Inventory'
  ,(CASE
        WHEN S1.P0 > FC.P0
        THEN TI.P0+OPO.P0-FP.P0
     ELSE
        [TI].[P0]+[S1].[P0]+[OPO].[P0]-[FC].[P0]-[FP].[P0]-[S2].[P0]) <--(LINE 184) THIS PAREN IS WHERE THE RED SQUIGGLE INDICATES "INCORRECT SYNTAX NEAR ')'
  ,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
FROM (SELECT EQId, P0 FROM #Month18Result WHERE TransactionType = 'TotalInventory')  TI
LEFT JOIN (SELECT EQId, P0 FROM #Month18Result WHERE TransactionType = 'Sales')  S1 
     ON S1.EQId = TI.EQId
LEFT JOIN (SELECT EQId, P0 FROM #Month18Result WHERE TransactionType = 'Open PO') as OPO 
     ON OPO.EQId = TI.EQId
LEFT JOIN (SELECT EQId, P0 FROM #Month18Result WHERE TransactionType = 'Forecast') as FC 
     ON FC.EQId = TI.EQId
LEFT JOIN (SELECT EQId, P0 FROM #Month18Result WHERE TransactionType = 'Further Process') as FP 
     ON FP.EQId = TI.EQId
LEFT JOIN (SELECT EQId, P0 FROM #Month18Result WHERE TransactionType = 'Safety Shock') as S2 
     ON S2.EQId = TI.EQId
```

If I remove the parens from the CASE statement, the squiggle moves to the first comma on line 185 with the same tooltip message as the paren on line 184.

This code is to test if S1.P0 is greater than FC.P0. If true, then use one formula. If false, use the other formula.

The temp table holds a unique ID, an NVAR for a category title, then 18 fields of INT numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgott close the case when Statmant with end

```
SELECT TI.EQId, 'Inventory'
  ,(CASE
        WHEN S1.P0 > FC.P0
        THEN TI.P0+OPO.P0-FP.P0
     ELSE
        [TI].[P0]+[S1].[P0]+[OPO].[P0]-[FC].[P0]-[FP].[P0]-[S2].[P0]) END AS SOMENAME
FROM (SELECT EQId, P0 FROM #Month18Result WHERE TransactionType = 'TotalInventory')  TI
LEFT JOIN (SELECT EQId, P0 FROM #Month18Result WHERE TransactionType = 'Sales')  S1 
     ON S1.EQId = TI.EQId
LEFT JOIN (SELECT EQId, P0 FROM #Month18Result WHERE TransactionType = 'Open PO') as OPO 
     ON OPO.EQId = TI.EQId
LEFT JOIN (SELECT EQId, P0 FROM #Month18Result WHERE TransactionType = 'Forecast') as FC 
     ON FC.EQId = TI.EQId
LEFT JOIN (SELECT EQId, P0 FROM #Month18Result WHERE TransactionType = 'Further Process') as FP 
     ON FP.EQId = TI.EQId
LEFT JOIN (SELECT EQId, P0 FROM #Month18Result WHERE TransactionType = 'Safety Shock') as S2 
     ON S2.EQId = TI.EQId
```

Answer (score 1):

Didn't check your query in details, but isn't there an "end" missing in the case statement?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

```
Searched CASE expression:
CASE
     WHEN Boolean_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END
```

Comment: WOW. I have been staring at that code for hours, and due to a single set of eyes, I visually saw the END until you pointed out it was missing. Thanks so much!